# Proving that a function is not one to one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Can you prove that this functions is not one-to-one?

$f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, defined by:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2&\text{if }x>-1\\
x-4&\text{if }x\le1
\end{cases}$$

I think there is something wrong in my book with this exercise.

Comment: I think it should be x-4 for x<= -1

Comment: Was the second condition supposed to read "$x-4 \;if\;x≤-1$" ?

Comment: Yes, I think that too, as I said , I think there is something wrong

Comment: Trusting that to be the case, then $f(-\frac 12)=f(\frac 12)$.

Comment: What have you done so far? Hint: I prefer this definition of $1-1$. A function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is 1-1 iff $x\neq y\Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$. If the function is not 1-1, then there exists $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @lulu The case from my book or your case?

Comment: @Bogdan15 if you wrap your formulas in  dollar signs it will make it math pretty.  There is a page floating around on shortcuts, if I find it I'll post, but basically use Latex. For examples you can use the edit button to view the underlying content for other questions posted and get ideas on how to use from there.

Comment: @Bogdan15  The case assuming $x≤-1$ (so not the book case).  The way the problem is presented, without the correction, this isn't even a function (as $f(0)=0\;and\;f(0)=-4$) so the question doesn't even make sense.  But I expect that's a simple typo.

Comment: you have to enclose the } or it won't pick up

Answer (score 1):

Stealing lulu's comment so we have an answer:  note that $f(-\frac 12)=\frac 14=f(\frac 12)$ so the function is not one-to-one.